# Error while deploying SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am getting this Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum error while deploying a SSIS package on a server for its respective job. I am able to check-in and all other stuff, just not deploy the packages for some reasons

[image: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum]

I have tried Uninstalling and reinstalling visual studios and repair SSDT as well but to no avail.

Let me know if there is a way to rectify and correct this error.
Below Link is the error screenshot.

Comment: And SSDT definitely includes the SSIS runtime packages? Is that named assembly definitely on the target system? Is it registered in the global assembly cache?

Comment: Can you execute the SSIS package and verify it works before you try to deploy it to SSISDB? If it works, my next best guess is perhaps you do not have permission to SSISDB.

Answer (score 0):

Try a repair of Visual Studio, that should help.
How to repair VS 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio